# test description notation for attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec

When I write RSpec tests, I often name `describe` blocks with a hash or period for instance and class methods.

```
describe "#do_stuff" do
  it "does instance stuff" do
    thing = Thing.new
    thing.do_stuff
    expect(thing.stuff_done?).to eq(true)
  end
end

describe ".do_more_stuff" do
  it "does class stuff" do
    Thing.do_more_stuff
    expect(thing.more_stuff_done?).to eq(true)
  end
end
```

Is there an equivalent for attributes? I need to test attribute default values and attributes which have special behavior because of custom readers.

Comment: What would you be testing with the attribute, exactly?

Comment: Are you testing that an attribute exists? Or do you want to `do_even_more_stuff` with the attribute?

Comment: Good question.  I need to test attribute default values and attributes which have special behavior because of custom readers. I've updated the question as well.

Comment: I believe the `#` and `.` prefaces in the `describe` are just conventions. They don't add any actual features right? I have never heard it before. The notation isn't a big deal as long as you are internally consistent with what you and your team write. If you aren't sure how to write the tests I can add an answer to that but I don't have much else on the notation side.

Comment: Yeah, they're just conventions. They came from the ruby community at large, rather than our team, so I was hoping to stay consistent with the ruby community. Perhaps the ruby community just doesn't have a convention for this and I should just use the `#` for properties as well.

Comment: I think there is no convention because you are working outside of how attributes are typically used. An attribute should not have any special logic behind it (or if it does, you have a different method that creates and you write tests for *that* method instead). You can write tests that say "This class has this attribute." Which would really be either of the `#` or `.` conventions you have been using depending on how you got to your attribute.